# How to offset the starting point of an image in a WPF image control (panning an image)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, pan

I'm trying to change the starting point of an image within a WPF image control, I can't seem to find a straight answer.

I'm trying to allow the user to pan and view a image which is larger than the image control.

Here is a [link to a screenshot](http://i1096.photobucket.com/albums/g324/thezaza101/wpfImageControl.jpg) of my app, and what i need it to do.

Just as an example, I want the starting point of to be (`image.Height/2`, `image.Width/2`) instead of (0,0). I need the starting point to be dynamically changeable via the C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your image control inside a scroll viewer.

```
<ScrollViewer 
    x:Name="MyScrollViewer"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Image .../>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then you can use the ScrollToVerticalOffset and ScrollToHorizontalOffset methods in code.

Comment: This was the easiest way, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this comes way too late, but I've found myself on a similar problem and `ScrollViewer` wouldn't work for me because I need to manage mouse interaction events on the image.

Instead, my solution consists on placing the `Image` inside a `Canvas`, then setting (in my case with a data binding) both `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties on said `Image`:

```xml
<Canvas>
    <Image Canvas.Left="{Binding MyOffset.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding MyOffset.Y}" />
</Canvas>
```